# C# capture process network traffic

Tags: c#, windows, networking, process, packet-capture

Can anyone point me in the right direction for some examples or docs which would help create a program that monitors the processes on a local host and gathers as much information about them if they are caught trying to communicate with a given URL and/or IP Address?

LE: I overlooked highlighting some constraints:
Whatever will be the result of this question (if any) will be built into an already existing CLI application which is run remotely with no access to GUI.

The environment is comprised of a very large number of hosts which get infected from time to time due to loose constraints so something that could be started and run in the background would be extremely helpful!

Comment: If you are using windows you can use the Resource Monitor and take a look at the Network tab

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added some of the constraints I am faced with which make using the resource monitor moot.

Comment: You are going to run this application on every host?

Comment: Just on the ones that are found to communicate with offending websites. This will be detected via proxy.